# Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

```
importScripts('js/jquery.js');
importScripts('js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js');
importScripts('cordova.js');
importScripts('DataBase.js');
importScripts('SaveData.js');

self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    queryDB(function(arr) {

        self.postMessage(e.data + arr);

    });


}, false);
```

here i tried to retrieve data from database and show in parent page using html 5 worker thread.But i get following error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Comment: HTML5 workers aren't attached to a `window`. You have to send your data back in a message.

Comment: Can u eloborate ur answer.Can u tell me how i read this array and pass back to the parent window.

Comment: If you need an answer in that level of detail, ask yourself whether a web worker is an appropriate way to do the job. If you're just reading data from a database a simple AJAX call and callback will suffice.

Comment: Actually i take data from database(LocalStorage).But it takes sometime so i need to handover that to worker thread.While worker thread is doing the job i need to display a loading message

Comment: why are you including jquery mobile into a webworker?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot importScript jQuery, because jQuery requires DOM access, which web workers don't have.

Answer (score 3):

If you experience this error with Web Workers using `importScripts` functionality, it's because the script you're importing may be referencing `window` object; this is not supported in Web Workers.

To fix this, do the following:

1. Put this code before any other code in the imported script:

```
var _window = this || self || window;
```

The above ensures that `self` (which is compatible with Web Workers) is called before unsupported `window`.

2. Replace all occurrences of `window` with `_window`.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, If i tried to check if window exist I got an error...