# How to clear Firestore IndexedDB persistence in a service worker in MV3 Chrome extension?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-chrome-extension

The Firestore [`enableIndexedDbPersistence`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#enableindexeddbpersistence) allows us to specify `forceOwnership: true` to specify that we're in a service worker context. This works great in MV3 Chrome Extension service worker. It starts the IndexedDB and I'm able to view the stored data in extension context.

However, when I call [`clearIndexedDbPersistence`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#enableindexeddbpersistence=), it fails because of "`window` is not defined" errors. The exact trace is this but it is probably not relevant:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Yl.delete (index.esm2017.js:6055:59)
    at index.esm2017.js:16720:26
    at index.esm2017.js:16717:19
    at index.esm2017.js:16308:54
```

To repro the issue, simply call `clearIndexedDbPersistence()` a few seconds after the call to `enableIndexedDbPersistence(firebase, { forceOwnership: true })` has finished, in a service worker in a MV3 Chrome extension.

Is there a temporary workaround, or a flag in Firestore, that will make this work? I did not find any open issues about this, so it is possible I am missing something, but I don't see what that could be.

Comment: It's a bug in firebase. See if they have a js file for service workers. If not, report the bug. A possible workaround may be `self.window = self` before importing their js - it'll work only in case they mistakenly used `window` to address the global scope and not for its DOM features.

Comment: Some helpful links here 

[1] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664665/window-is-not-defined-service-worker  )

[ 2 ] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136898/uncaught-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined )

[3] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194103/error-in-event-handler-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined-chrome-extension-w)

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks I'll report it in their github repo.

Comment: @VaidehiJamankar Thanks but all the links are unrelated to this particular issue.